# css3 transition accordion menu

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I made an accordion menu that replaces the select form control, and I want to use css3 transitions to make it expand/contract smoothly.
Here's a link to the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hKsCD/4/

To achieve the desired effect I need to animate the height of each of the links, but I'm not sure how to do that. CSS3 transitions are confusing. O_o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.accordion {
    height: 20px; /*define height to start from*/
    transition: height 2s;
    -moz-transition: height 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: height 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: height 2s; /* Opera */
}
.accordion.expanded {
    height: 400px;/*desired height when expanded*/
}
```

you have to be careful though when the height varies from one element to another, you should use a max-width workaround in these cases as "height:auto" won't work.

e.g. replace `height` in example above with `max-height` and in the expanded state set `max-height` to something the element will never reach (not too high though, as speed of animation is calculated in respect to the height to be animated --> a max-width that's too high (e.g. 9999px) results in an animation that's so fast you don't notice it)

Comment: Each of the accordions will have a different number of options, and thus different heights. I tried using max-height, but that doesn't work because when the class expanded gets removed, all of the options (<a> elements) disappear instantly. The transition needs to be applied to all of the options not the menu itself. I tried applying a height transition on the options, but it's not animating. Here is my attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/hKsCD/5/

Comment: After playing around with it some more, I got it figured out. It just needs a little polish. http://jsfiddle.net/hKsCD/6/
Thank you for your help.